# Salesforce Login issue

Tags: login, issue

I have lost my phone as I have no salesforce authenticator or phone number.
How can login into my org.

Can I login with custom domain?security token.
please help me

Comment: Check this link it may helpful to you:https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BaW2IAK

Comment: You have to raise it via email or twitter. I prefer twitter. The handle is @AskSalesforce. They will raise a case on you behalf and get it sorted.